# Glitchy grid in QGraphicsView::drawBackground

Tags: c++, qt, qgraphicsview

I'm trying to properly display a grid pattern on `QGraphicsView::drawBackground`. Everything seems to work fine until I try to move an item added to a scene.

I add the line in MainWindow like this:

```
   QPen _Pen;
   _Pen.setColor(Qt::red);
   _Pen.setWidth(3);

   QGraphicsLineItem* _Line=new QGraphicsLineItem(0,0,100,100);
   _Line->setPen(_Pen);
   _Line->setVisible(true);
   _Line->setFlags(QGraphicsLineItem::ItemIsSelectable | QGraphicsLineItem::ItemIsMovable);

   m_scene->addItem(_Line);
```

Methods of GraphicsView:

```
GraphicsView::GraphicsView() : cellSize(20)
{
   setSizePolicy(QSizePolicy::Expanding,QSizePolicy::Expanding);
}

void GraphicsView::drawBackground(QPainter *p, const QRectF &crect)
{
   p->save();
   p->setPen(QPen(Qt::black,1));

   for (int x = crect.topLeft().x(); x < crect.bottomRight().x(); x += cellSize)
      for (int y = crect.topLeft().y(); y < crect.bottomRight().y(); y += cellSize)
         p->drawPoint(x, y);

   p->restore();
}
```

The problem can be seen here:

[image: Demonstration]

When I move the item, it leaves a trail of grid dots behind it, which are not aligned to the original grid.

I don't understand where this error comes from. Have I done something wrong?

Answer (score 2):

I can think of 2 possible issues:

1. Change the view update mode. The options are described [here](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qgraphicsview.html#ViewportUpdateMode-enum).

   `setViewportUpdateMode(SmartViewportUpdate);` or `setViewportUpdateMode(FullViewportUpdate);`
2. The smear may be caused by the item bounding rectangle of the item being half a pixel too small.

(I realize this question is old, but maybe it will help someone else)

Answer (score 0):

The region you're given in `drawBackground` is not always the full view. When something on the scene changes, you're given only the relevant region to redraw. And you're starting in the top left corner of different "moving" regions.

One way to fix this would be to make the initial `x` and `y` multiples of `cellSize`:

```
for (int x = (int)crect.left()/cellSize*cellSize; x < crect.right(); x += cellSize)
    for (int y = (int)crect.top()/cellSize*cellSize; y < crect.bottom(); y += cellSize)
```